# Regex to remove white spaces after `<` and `/` in HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex, xml

I have a text like this and want to eliminate white spaces only after `<` and `/` charater to avoid errors while parsing it.

Input:

```
< lesson id="024AC57B0CA72ADE" classids="5B111F8CD42D0943" / >
```

Output:

```
<lesson id="024AC57B0CA72ADE" classids="5B111F8CD42D0943" />
```

Note:
I don't want to eliminate white space before `>` everytime. Only just after `/` as
this is vaild

```
</lesson >
```

but this is not

```
</ lesson>
```

Regex I tried but couldn't cover all cases:

```
\s*< |\/ \\s*
```

https://regex101.com/r/0LuV0O/1

Comment: Why don't you just load the file in a text editor and then search/replace on those issues, and then save the file for use? Doing this programmatically with regex seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Andy This XML file could be large and hard to find the lines with format issues. A check could really help in automation and figuring out issues at early stages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of this problem as removing the spaces after `<` and `/`.

```js
'< lesson id="024AC57B0CA72ADE" classids="5B111F8CD42D0943" / >'
  .replace(/([</])\s*/g, '$1')
```

Output:

```
<lesson id="024AC57B0CA72ADE" classids="5B111F8CD42D0943" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric! Works like a charm. Just being curious what does '$1' means here?

Comment: @AayushJain the parentheses create a "Capture Group" for the `<` and `/` occurrences. So when we replace the regex with `$1`, we are effectively extracting the content of the first (and only one in the regex) capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regular expression that you can use to remove white spaces after < and / in an HTML tag:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=[<\/])\s+', '', html_string)
```

This regular expression uses a positive lookbehind assertion to match any white space characters (\s+) that appear immediately after a < or / character in the HTML string. The matched white space is then replaced with an empty string using the re.sub() method.